# I have an issue with consuming a web service in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, client-server

I have some problem with consuming web service wsdl php client. 
I need to read all information from the service but he return this java.lang.NullPointerException but if I limit at 100 its works. I don't know where is the problem.

**This my code**

```
 ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 
 $client = new soapclient("http://localhost:8080/ProjectServices/services/Services?wsdl");
 $param = array(__function__ => array('requete' => $sql,'limit' => $limit,'offset' => $Ndeb));
 $response = $client->__soapCall("listproduit", $param);
 var_dump($response);
```

Comment: What do you set as limit when you want to get all information?

Comment: like 200 cause i have a service who retourn the count of listproduit i use this response for limit but if i use it he retourn null